Is 'I don't want to have anything to do with them anymore, she told' correct?
I read on one oxford book that you always have to have an object (pronoun,noun) after the reporting verb tell, nevertheless I have heard native speakers say something along the lines of my example. I agree that you always need an object for tell in reported speech, but when that's not the case, is it possible to use it this way?

No, it's not. The book is correct.

Bear in mind that although to tell isn't normally intransitive (except in the childish threat to a wrongdoing sibling: "I'm telling!" with implied object our parents), it can be monotransitive (He tells lies) or ditransitive (She told the child a story).

Is 'I don't want to have anything to do with them anymore, she told' correct?
she said is correct  Please see this also. told + indirect object

Two minor corrections: we don’t read on books, but in them. And Oxford, being a proper noun, is capitalized.

It is not correct to say

"I don't want to have anything to do with them anymore", she told.

but then, it is incorrect to say

She told, "I don't want to have anything to do with them anymore"

This is because for reporting direct speech, you can't use "told" unless you provide an indirect object.  Hence it would have to be either

"I don't want to have anything to do with them anymore", she told me.

or

She told how she didn't want to have anything to do with them anymore.

which works because it's now indirect speech and therefore the object of "told."

How she didn't want to have anything to do with them anymore, she told

is odd but technically correct.
